# Is there any significance to this return statement?

Tags: c++, return, boolean, implicit-conversion

I was wondering if there was any significance in a part of a code I am seeing that involves

```
return (num!=0);
```

where num is an int. And this is the return statement of a boolean function that wants to return TRUE if `num != 0`, and false if `num = 0`.

I am not sure if there is an hidden significance to this, but I am not seeing why they cannot just simply write:

```
return num;
```

Here is the code I saw:

```
bool SemClass::cut(int &a, int &b, int &c) 
{
  int num = 0;    
  check(a, num);
  check(b, num );
  check(c, num);
  return (num != 0);
}
```

Comment: my suspicion is that this person doesn't know that an int will be converged to a bool where num!=0 is true and false otherwise.

Comment: Yes, sorry this is C++.

Comment: `return (num!=0)` is a shorthand way of writing `if(num!=0) return true; else return false;`

Comment: Returning a bool instead of an int that is language specific behavior has some severe difference in readability and portability of the code.

Comment: I see. So in C++, in this case, I can just simply use "return num"?

Comment: In this case, In C++, writing `num` and `num!=0` are both fine. However, `num!=0` might make it more obvious that the method is returning a boolean. Technically, only an integer of value `0` would equate to a boolean `false`, while all other values would equate to a boolean `true`. By writing `num!=0`, It is made explicit that the method would return `true` if `num` is not equivalent to 0 and `false` if it is. Implicit conversions: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_cast

Comment: By returning `num` you'll simply return it's value and NOT the result of the evaluation of `num!=0`. Also if you want to return `num` you'll have to change the return type to `int`.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear. I meant I wanted to return a boolean, but I can return num and implicitly casts the "int" to a boolean.

Comment: Some compilers will give a "narrowing" warning on 'return num'. Having the extra test there changes the return type from int to bool, thus getting rid of the warning.

Comment: Also. Are the following equivalent: "return (num != 0)" and "return num!= 0" I am not sure if the added complexity of the returns statement would require the parenthesis.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with this code except the redundant parentheses. Find something else to worry about.

Comment: I don't see the problem here. The person who wrote this `return` statement is just interested whether `num` is equal or not to zero. If you simply return `num` (that is change the function to return integer result) and you still are only interested in the thing I wrote above, you have to do the check outside the function. This might lead to code redundancy if the function is called at multiple locations in the code since we'll be writing an `if` statement that does the check over and over again.

Comment: Checking if something is not zero and checking whether something is `true` is the exact same thing in C and C++. You'll only ever get problems if you try to calculate with this.

Answer (score 6):

The value 0 for integral, floating-point, and unscoped enumeration and the null pointer and the null pointer-to-member values become false when returned as a `boolean` by implicit conversion. Other values such as 1, 2, 3, 4 etc. map to true. This convention was established in original C, via its flow control statements; C didn't have a boolean type at the time.

Implicit conversions: [en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_cast](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_cast)

In this case, in C++, writing `num` and `num!=0` are both fine. However, `num!=0` might make it more obvious that the method is returning a boolean. Technically, only an integer of value `0` would equate to a boolean false, while all other values would equate to a boolean true. By writing `num!=0`, It is made explicit that the method would return true if num is not equivalent to 0 and false if it is.

Good practice dictates that if it's a genuine truth value, then you should use a `boolean` as it makes it very clear to the caller what will be returned. When returning an `integer`, it could be seen as a code/enum type value.

Therefore, `num!=` is preferred to `num` in this case. The brackets are not required however. Some compilers will also issue a warning if you return an `integer` when the method is supposed to return a `boolean`.

Comment: On the other hand, the `!= 0` is as superfluous as the brackets. Even if the function was changed to return an integer, (almost) all of its uses in boolean contexts would be equally valid.

Comment: @filmor `num` and `num!=0` are logically equivalent; that is not in dispute. Good practice (disputably, of course, as always) however may dictate that you explicitly convert the `integer` into a `boolean`.

Comment: This (convert stuff explicitly) may hold for more complex types, but implicit boolean conversion is IMHO a good thing that should be used wherever possible. This `return` is a good start :)

Answer (score 2):

The author is being (excessively) careful on two counts:

1. The parentheses are redundant.
2. Any numeric type in C++ has an implicit conversion to `bool`: if the number compares to zero then it's `false`, else it's `true`.

Personally I prefer the naked `return num;` as I find that clearer.

(Note that in C, the relational operators return the `int` types 1 and 0, rather than `true` and `false`).

Answer (score 2):

The author may have written `return num`, the compiler would generate the exact same binary. Here, the author tries to be explicit and to make as easy as possible to the reader to guess what the function returns.

When a quick reader sees `return num` knowing that `num` is an `int` and the current function returns a `bool`, (s)he needs to stop for a fraction of a second to a few seconds (depending on its concentration and ease regarding C++) to remember that an integer is implicitly convertible to a boolean with the mapping `0 -> false, anything else -> true`. So, why not write that down?

When the quick reader sees `return num!=0`, (s)he guesses that the current function returns a boolean (it could be otherwise, but it would be suspicious) and comprehend easily what the return value means.

As a rule of thumb, I'd advise to pick the more explicit writing when it does not hurt the reading and when it takes only a few more (or less) characters. Don't forget that you do not write code for the compiler, you write code for the dozens of other developers who works or will work with you(r code). C++ may be less common in 20 years, it would be great if your program could be easily understood not only by gurus but by everyone (I'm generalizing there, not only talking about the implicit boolean conversion).